# Cannot undo or redo (greyed out 95% of the time)

Tags: qgis-3

QGIS is amazing, but I cannot undo or redo on basic actions. Here is only one example.
I have 5 layers in my project, and I turn one layer off. I cannot undo with control + z or edit>undo.

I am on Windows 10 x64 running 3.26. I have had this issue for all versions of 3.xx which I have used.

What might be the issue?

Comment: Undo/repeat is only intended for feature editing, not for symbology, loaded layers, etc.

Comment: There's an option to undo/redo symbology changes, **View** -> **Panels** -> **Layer Styling**, this panel allows you to undo/redo changes.

Comment: Hi Mayo, thanks for the response.
I'm guessing that undo has not been designed into QGIS due to software design etc?
I think it would be useful to have Undo for programme operations such as layer operations in case the user makes a mistake.
For example, a group of layers is accidently deleted instead of ungrouped. This action cannot be undone. Such a mistake can take lots of time to fix